# Subscript out of range, VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

so I have this line of code

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long
j = 18

For i = 3 To 47
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills").Range("E" & i) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainPage").Range("B" & j) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills").Range("B" & i)
            j = j + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

My problem is as follows,
First on the `If ....`  line I had object required error, now I fixed that (I thought) but now on the next line `sheetSkills("B" & j)....` I get subscript out of range error. anyone any ideas? I can't figure it out really

Comment: Do you have worksheets named "MainPage" and "Skills" in the active workbook when this runs? That's the only potential subscript error I can see in this code - both `i` and `j` are constrained by the loop.

Comment: I have the worksheets named MainPage and Skills yes, since calling it Sheet1 or Sheet 2 would be awkward code imho

Comment: Please update/add the current code that you are trying...I don't see `wsSkills` anywhere.  Also, if you're trying to reference a range on the `wsSkills` you need to use `wsSkills.Range("B"&j)` or `wsSkills.Cells(j,2)`

Comment: The key word was "active" workbook. When you use `Application.Worksheets("Whatever")`, it's looking for that worksheet name in only the active workbook.  If you have more than one open and the wrong one has focus, you may or may not find it. See @urdearboy's answer for the better way to approach this.

Comment: My current line of code where I get the error is this

```ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainPage").Range("B" & j)  = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills").Range("B" & i) ```

The Sheet names are correct and the Column letters are correct aswell

Answer (score 1):

1. *Maybe* your code is looking to another book? Try `ThisWorkbook.Sheets`
2. Add `Option Explicit` to force variable declaration (although this is not the source of your problem)
3. Last, a value transfer should be `Range.Value = Range.Value`

The only other error that I can see is that your sheet names are not exact matches. I ran this code with no issues (and yours). If your actual sheet name has a lagging space or some other character that is not immediately obvious at first glance, this will give you `Subscript Out of Range` as this needs to be **exact** match.

---

```
Sub Skills()

Dim j As Long, i As Long
j = 18

For i = 3 To 47
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills").Range("E" & i) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainPage").Range("B" & j).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills").Range("E" & i).Value
            j = j + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

---

You can use this to test that your sheet names are being found. If either of these lines error our, it means VBA can't find the sheet on your book.

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Skills")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MainPage")

End Sub
```

Comment: I have copied the names of the sheets in the active workbook, I have no other workbooks open aswell, and the copied names pasted between the " " inside the code.
I used your code, aswell as my own and I keep getting the same error, Subscript is out of range...
I have both sheets available in the workbook The "Value transfer" you reffered to is basically in a transfer of a name in cell Sheets("Skills").Range("B" & i) 
So I guess a string.
Also I edited the column letter in the last Sheets("Skills") reference

Comment: Solution Verified! The error lay in the MainPage name somewhere, I really have no idea where the name error came from but now I changed that name to "Main" and the code works PERFECT!! thanks all!